# how to set own file mime type

Tags: android, mime-types, addition

after digging into tens of question about how to associate custom file to my application, here i am to ask for the definitive question:
how to add the mime type using a *FileOutputStream*?

I'll try to explain:
my application writes the "lorenzoff" files, it's false but let's say without any extension. I know that Android use the mime type and ok, i understood that and i added this intent-filter to my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:host="" android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="application/wtf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now, i want to create my new files with their contents, let's say

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("lorenzoff"));
os.writeInt(1);
os.writeInt(2);
os.writeInt(3);
os.close();
```

Inspecting the newly created file with a file system browsing application (Astro), i can see that it has no mime type and, we are arrived, i cannot *VIEW* it by my application (it has no association).

The question: how to write the mime type so that i can read "application/wtf" inspecting the file properties?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you are completely misunderstand what MIME type is.
You must not write mime type into file. MIME only describes the type of a content (eg.: file)

When a file browser try to open a file (send an intent in android) the file type is determined by it's extension not the content.

After determination the browser will launch the appropriate intent.
The file browsers usually will be able to handle standard mime types like image, video, audio, text or pdf.